# Roslaunch does not exit after processes finish

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I've created a roslaunch that does all the work and finished cleanly. The problem is that it stays alive and to fully terminate the program I need to ctrl-c. I've read in an old ticket that it's because the core keeps running (for non-specified reasons).

Is it possible to force the launch to exit after all processes end?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124721/roslaunch-does-not-exit-after-processes-finish/) by [JohnMdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11471/johnmdz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you're looking for the `required="true"` option to the `<node>` tag in roslaunch.

Take a look at the description of the [node tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnMdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11471/johnmdz/) on 2014-02-05**:
Thank you! Worked like a charm!

**Comment by [Sasinister](https://answers.ros.org/users/33069/sasinister/) on 2017-12-29**:
Thanks! Been looking for this for ages!